# Can I user anchors with the scrolling animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I wanted to find out if I could use anchors with the scrolling animation on my second page? Just like this example here that I've used for my site: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M

I have tried to use both but find that there's a conflict between the animation and anchors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'forthPage'],
                    slidesNavigation: true
                });
            });
        </script>
```

If I can't use the anchor feature with the animation, is there an alternative that I could use instead? Would this mean that I would need to make my own way to scroll to other pages easily?

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't see why not. They are not exclusive at all. You are probably using the wrong state CSS class. `fp-viewing-X-Y`. Make sure it matches what you can see with your inspector.
Provide a reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen to show us your problem otherwise.

Comment: When you say wrong state CSS class, what do you mean? Do you mean the jquery.fullPage.css? As this is what I have included on the html webpage.

Comment: Provide a reproduction of your issue in jsfiddle or codepen for a better understanding.